# how to implement Restfull api using laravel

Tags: android, laravel, api

now i'm developing android app for the existing web site.so now i want to implement simple Api for the post data (to laravel api from android app) and get data (from laravel api  to android app).so i read lots of articles but no any proper way to satisfy my way. any one have idea about this and what is the flow of the this api. thank you

Comment: look for laravel passport

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started is using [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers).

That way you can implement a simple CRUD REST API (so much caps).

[image]

Then use [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) for authenticating the consumer of the API.

**Steps to take**

1. [Define Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#defining-models) matching your database tables
2. Create a [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) with artisan

   ```
   php artisan make:controller PhotoController --resource
   ```
3. Define the route e.g.:

   ```
   Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
   ```
4. Implement the resource controllers functions with the behaviour you expect
5. If the API works as you want it to: it's time to shield it with credentials. I recommend using [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport) for this.